# Ionic 3 - Polyfill for ES6 in IE11 Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, polyfills

I am aware that Ionic have stated that they will not be supporting IE11 - however I am still currently obliged by work to try and come up with a workaround of some sort if possible!

The issue I am having is the main.js file built by Ionic in the dev environment  is throwing an error in IE11 due to it using template literals.

I have created a polyfills.ts file which includes the following

*polyfills.ts*

```
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/fn/string/raw';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'hammerjs';
```

and in my *main.ts* file

```
import './polyfills'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

However it doesn't seem to be resolving the issue. Am I perhaps missing a module from core-js that would solve this issue?

Any advice as always is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version of ionic app scripts.

I had

> @ionic/app-scripts: 3.1.0

updating to 3.1.2 resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

## Fix

Your import is wrong.

```
import './polyfills.ts'
```

It should be

```
import './polyfills'
```

You might have other issues beyond this, but this is the first mistake making your current attempt a noop.

Comment: Thank you! Did not solve the issue however. I think the polyfills are being loaded after some of the other application code, despite them being placed at the top of the main,ts file. Any suggestions?