# Angular polyfills for es6

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I was going through the the angular docs listed below and some other links on the web regarding angular. If all the code is written in Typescript what is the need for es6 polyfills. Also my understanding is that eventually webpack transpiles the code to ES5, so where do the polyfills get used?

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

https://github.com/xiaomoinfo/Angular2/blob/master/how-angular-works/inventory-app/src/polyfills.ts

[Ionic 3 - Polyfill for ES6 in IE11 Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266254/ionic-3-polyfill-for-es6-in-ie11-not-working)

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what polyfills are used for.  They allow you to use modern functionality in older browsers by adding support for missing features.  For example, if you were using promises in your code, then you would need a polyfill for the promises to work in an older browser like IE11.  This has nothing to do with transpiling to ES5.  A promise transpiles to ES5 is still a promise object and needs a polyfill.

Comment: My question is clear. ES6 polyfills augment Javascript. If typescript is used with angular why add add es6 polyfills. I do understand the meaning of polyfills.

Comment: Probably because angular relies on some ES6 features that need those polyfills.  It's pretty clear in the angular link you posted: ***"Angular is built on the latest standards of the web platform. Targeting such a wide range of browsers is challenging because they do not support all features of modern browsers. You compensate by loading polyfill scripts ("polyfills") for the browsers that you must support. The table below identifies most of the polyfills you might need."***

Comment: I don't think thats a good design. When I use jQuery to get cross browser functionality, there was no need for Polyfills. jQuery used to take care of browser specifics. I do understand what you are saying but perhaps is not an answer. Hence asking.

Comment: jQuery just supplies its own polyfills (usually in a non-standard way) for things it needs (technically they aren't polyfills because they don't mimic a standard, but they solve the problem for jQuery).  The reason Angular does what it does is because it's way more efficient when run in modern browsers because it doesn't have all this extra baggage around, it just uses what the browser supplies.  But, if you want to run in older browsers, it provides a means to do that.

Comment: Because of what jQuery was doing, it got a bit bloated, even when run in modern browsers, so they had to come out with a new version (3.x) that eliminates some of the bloat, relies on features built-in to browsers and is not compatible with older browsers.  The polyfill scheme is actually a much better way to do things because one body of code can be used with all the supported browsers by just adding polyfills.  More modular.

Comment: The other problem with jQuery not using actual polyfills is that they have a lot of non-standard behavior.  Their deferreds are still not programmed identically to ES6 promises.  That's not a good path to go.

Comment: Language and Library are not the same. That is all. To use ES2015+ syntax in older runtimes, you need a transpiler. To use ES2015+ standard library facilities in older runtimes, you need polyfills. TypeScript is a "bring your own polyfill" language. It contains the declarations for newer library features, to support typechecking, but not implementations of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is built using features found in a modern browser.  When run in that modern browser, it uses built-in features of that browser.

In order to run in older browsers that do not have those built-in features, you can add "polyfills" which add the newer features to older browsers.

Some compatibility issues with older browsers can be solved with transpiling such as transpiling ES6 language syntax back to something that works in ES5.  But, other functionality such as a `Map` object in ES6 needs to be polyfilled so that it can be used in an older browser.

From your link on Angular:

> Angular is built on the latest standards of the web platform. Targeting such a wide range of browsers is challenging because they do not support all features of modern browsers.
>
> You compensate by loading polyfill scripts ("polyfills") for the browsers that you must support. The table below identifies most of the polyfills you might need.

---

This is a design approach that gives you a code design that is optimized for the latest browsers, but can be made to work with older browsers with some additional work (including some polyfills).

Libraries such as early versions of jQuery picked a different approach.  Rather than use polyfills, they just created their own implementation of features they needed (such as deferreds) and used them in all their code regardless of browser.  While this was easy for the developer to deploy, it ran into problems over time.  The jQuery code got bloated as it added code that was now built-in to modern browsers and some of the jQuery implementation of things were incompatible with modern standards (such as Promises).

---

So, some of Angular's functionality requires libraries that are implemented in ES6.  Transpiling does not remove the need for those libraries.  They still need to exist.  That's what polyfills are for.  With angular, you decide what level of older browser you want to support and you then add the required polyfills.  Angular does not do that for you automatically.

Comment: In my tsconfig, I specify the target as ES5 and the module system as CommonJs or requirejs - what would be the need for ES6 polyfills?

Comment: Depends on if you use ES2015 (ES6) library features. If not, the framework should depend on any polyfills it uses and that should not be a concern of the app author.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - Angular does not automatically pull in the desired polyfills.  After you've decided what older browsers you want to support and identified which polyfills you need for that, you then have to add those polyfills yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00 I see.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing - Do you understand the difference between transpiling ES6 syntax to ES5 syntax and providing an implementation of an ES6 library such as a `Map` object?  You can transpile an ES6 statement like `for (let x of y)`  into some more verbose ES5 code that accomplishes the same thing.  But, you can't transpile `var x = new Map()` into ES5 code.  You need an implementation of a `Map` object (written in ES5 compatible code).  That's what a polyfill provides.